# Laravel API controller | How can i hash the password in this "update" method of the controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is the method inside my API controller which is suppose to update the User data. One of the columns is password which is suppose to be hashed before insert.

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->userRepository->findWithoutFail($id);
    
    if (empty($user)) {
        return $this->sendResponse([
            'error' => true,
            'code' => 404,
        ], 'User not found');
    }
    $input = $request->except(['api_token']);
    try {
        if ($request->has('device_token')) {
            $user = $this->userRepository->update($request->only('device_token'), $id);
        } else {
            $customFields = $this->customFieldRepository->findByField('custom_field_model', $this->userRepository->model());
           
            $user = $this->userRepository->update($input, $id);
            
            foreach (getCustomFieldsValues($customFields, $request) as $value) {
            
                $user->customFieldsValues()
                    ->updateOrCreate(['custom_field_id' => $value['custom_field_id']], $value);
            }
        }
    } catch (ValidatorException $e) {
        return $this->sendError($e->getMessage(), 401);
    }

    return $this->sendResponse($user, __('lang.updated_successfully', ['operator' => __('lang.user')]));
}
```

Right now, upon updating the User data using this method, the raw text of the password is inserted to the User table. I want it to be hashed using the following code. But i do not know where should this go in the method above. Can someone please help ??

```
 $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
```

Example of the body of request which would come to update :

```
{"id":"147","name":"tipumon","email":"a@gmail.com","phone":"9898365627","useraddress":"test address","password":"passwordtext","api_token":"<apiTokenstring>","bio":"","media":{"id":null,"name":null,"url":"https://example.com/public/images/image_default.png","thumb":"https://example.com/public/images/image_default.png","icon":"https://example.com/public/images/image_default.png","formated_size":null}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved myself.

```
   public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
         
        $user = $this->userRepository->findWithoutFail($id);
        
        if (empty($user)) {
            return $this->sendResponse([
                'error' => true,
                'code' => 404,
            ], 'User not found');
        }
        $input = $request->except(['api_token']);
        $input['password'] = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
```

Comment: why not have the repository do it?